# Does Visual Studio 2015 have float.h?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I may be going crazy here.

Visual Studio 2013 has `float.h` located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\float.h
```

There are references to `float.h` in the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bs3y5ya.aspx) for Visual Studio 2015.

Yet in the directory Visual Studio 2015 is located at, there's no float.h:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\float.h (doesn't exist)
```

Has it been removed?

Comment: You can use VS but can't figure out how to search your hard drive for a file?

Comment: Obviously I searched for it, with the only file being in Visual Studio 2013 directory...

Microsoft could've removed it from 2015 for all I know, I'm just looking for a more comprehensive answer as to why it doesn't seem to exist with all my other includes.

Comment: The [CRT was split](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx), for VS2015 you'll typically find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt.  This should never be a problem in a project you create from a template or when you use vcvaralls.bat, avoid making it a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @HansPassant, I wasn't aware. I managed to find the header in that directory :-). Unfortunately it's Intel's C++ compiler looking for float.h in the incorrect directory (as their own float.h relies upon Visual Studio's).