# when building pixman library, the prompt always says "can not find xxx.h(the std header"?

Tags: c++, pixman

I'm using Windows 10 system, VS2015. I want to build pixman-0.34.0 now. 
The tutorials here: http://cairographics.org/end_to_end_build_for_win32/ tells me to use these prompt lines:

```
   cd %ROOTDIR%\pixman\pixman
   sed s/-MD/-MT/ Makefile.win32 > Makefile.fixed
   move /Y Makefile.fixed Makefile.win32
   make -f Makefile.win32 "CFG=release"
```

however, the powershell(or msys64) always tells me that

"pixman-0.34.0\pixman\pixman.h(105): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory"

which is very strange because < stdint.h > does exist in my computer!  If I create a new .cpp file which includes < stdint.h >, I could successfully compile it.

I tried to move all the source code from the pixman's root directory to VS's include directory...
The prompt now tells that no < time.h > file.

I guess I need to set include directory somewhere, but I dont know how to do it.

It almost drives me crazy now. I have spent a whole day trying to solve it but none of my try works.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

See also this quesiton: [Does Visual Studio 2015 have float.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913018/does-visual-studio-2015-have-float-h)

Float.h got moved for VS 2015.  I was able to build pixman by updating Makefile.win32.common in the root source directory, line 28:

```
BASE_CFLAGS = -nologo -I. -I$(top_srcdir) -I$(top_srcdir)/pixman -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include"
```